# Javascript createElement("TEXTAREA") shows up as [object...]

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to input a text area in a onMouseOver description for a HTML list. I decided to try the .createElement('TEXTAREA') yet it returns [object HTMLTextAreaElement]. (Also if you could tell me an easier way to put HTML tags without using text areas that would be swell XD)
Here is the code:

```
   } else if (a === 'var') {
      var textarea = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
    var t = document.createTextNode("<code>, <var>, <samp> and <kgb>");
    textarea.appendChild(t);
      desc = "When defining some computer code in HTML there is four options, " + textarea;
   } else {
    desc = 'This item needs a description.';
   }

   document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML=desc;
}
```

Oh by the way I'm new to this stuff so go easy on meh.

Answer (score 0):

The `textarea` is actually an instance of the HTMLTextAreaElement class, not a string. You will have to append it using DOM manipulation:

```
document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('desc').appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc));    
document.getElementById('desc').appendChild(textarea);
```

Comment: Thank you! Though is there a reason why I have to also use    document.getElementById('desc').appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc)); and not document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML=desc; then add the ...appendchild(textarea);?

Comment: If you're going to use *innerHTML*, you might as well just insert the new nodes as HTML. At the very least, store the value of `document.getElementById('desc')` and reuse it.

Comment: I should of pasted the whole code. It was just a very specific question I had. Thank you that makes sense although I already did that earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
    var t = document.createTextNode("you will learn.");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

first create the text area then append the text to it.

Comment: I actually got this idea from reading this same example somewhere else lol. The textNode is appended to textarea with textarea.appendChild(t)..

Answer (score 0):

`createElement` returns a node object, which then you can append to another element, in this case the description box on mouse over:

```
var desc = document.getElementById('desc');
var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
var message = document.createTextNode('When defining some computer code in HTML there is four options: <code>, <var>, <samp> and <kgb>');

function showTextarea() {
    desc.textContent = '';
    desc.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.appendChild(message);

    desc.removeEventListener('mouseover', showTextarea);
}

desc.addEventListener('mouseover', showTextarea);
```

JSFiddle example:

**http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/r0mch2g7/**

Comment: THANK YOU! This gave me some ideas too, there are so many ways to do the same thing lol. Though I Don't really want the whole description in the text area, which is why the textarea and desc were separate. I only want the HTML tags in the textarea.